# How to implement/Simulate a job scheduler?

Tags: java, c++, scheduler, job-scheduling

I want to develop a basic Job scheduler that takes up new jobs as they come into the queue and schedule them and rearrange jobs to meet their requirements.

I tried implementing the Scheduler as a Queue of objects where the object is of the form

```
class queueItem{
    job j;
    long start,end,duration;
    Boolean isStart,isEnd;
}
```

So is this a decent approach to simulate job scheduling or is there a better implementation to schedule a list of jobs given their start,end,duration , say using one of the Pre-Emptive algorithms.
This might be in any language for that matter.Just some hints on how to approach it would be great.
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: You don't schedule into a queue; it's first come first serve.

Comment: you are confusing algorithm, datastructure and implementation in your question. If you dont specify the constraints and requirements, there is no good scheduling algorithm. @ChiefTwoPencils a simple queue is FIFO .

Comment: And what is First Come(in) First Serve(out)? There's no "scheduling" there. op says they want to base it on duration. @UmNyobe

Comment: This isn't a great imp. a `queueItem` in all reality is a [`N`]`ode`. You should have a [`J`]`ob` with these attributes that a node holds. A `queue` is like a line, you get into it an you will be served in the order which you were received. It seems like you probably want to optimize your jobs; is that right?

Comment: Yes I would like to optimize the jobs so that the no of rejected jobs would be less. So the priority is kind of a global one to maximize the jobs done.I just want to know how to design the Data-structure for handling the scheduling of the jobs in an ideal/optimal way.

Answer (score 2):

It's too board for the meaning of scheduler.
- What's the nature of the jobs being scheduled?
- What's the requirement and strategy for scheduling?

In general, a scheduler consist of few logical componenets

1. job picker, a logic to pick the next job.
2. context switcher, perform the actual job switching(saving/restoring context info,   stop/starting jobs)
3. trigger, this is usually timer, but other events are also useful.
4. optionally accounting, which may in turn provide stats to the job picker.

For a system to support pre-emptive scheduling, jobs must be interruptible.

For a decent scheduler, IMO it should support priorities, suspend and block for event (time and other event).

This may has the following data layout:

- LIST active [ ... ];   // array of list of jobs, one list per priority
- LIST slept;            // suspended jobs
- LIST zombie;        // finished job, waiting for cleanup
- JOB* current_job;
- time elapsed;        // elapsed time since job switched
- time quantum;       // budget of current job until next switching

N.B. This may be over-simplified.